# How to make a selectable list in HTML5

Tags: javascript, css, html, listbox

I am trying to mimic a listbox as what would be available in MS visual studio. I have found HTML elements

select 
and datalist

The problem is that these are really for data entry. What I had in mind is to have search results shown in a list but they are selectable? I need to know the index of the item(s) chosen so I can retrieve more additional detail for a subsequent screen. The elements above are more like drop downs. I want something like a textbox with a scroll bar that allows for multi select. Is that possible for HTML5?

I know VS had a form toolbox item that did just that.

Any advice?

Thanks in advance.

Matt

Comment: divs with checkboxes inside work, as do <select multiple> if you're lazy.

Comment: look into bootstrap or jQuery <select> upgraders than offer selections, filtering, etc. in short, you just code a dumb old <select> and the script turns it into an awesome list widget.

Comment: why not loop the results into individual inputs with checkbox?

Comment: Did you discover a solution for this? I'm brand new to HTML but coming from Windows Phone development. Looking to incorporate a very standard selectable list, possible with checkboxes or some indication of what items in the list are selected to perform some action thereafter.